# how to expose a specific https port on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, https

i want to open up port 8080 to https connections.
[image]

but the port number is locked at 443 for all https connections. http is also locked at 80 and ssh at 22.

the reason i want to do this is because the image below shows a dockerized django project working on my machine

[image]

but the image below shows the docker container not connecting in my ec2 container

[image]

how can i open up port 8080 to connect to my ec2 container from my browser.

#### update

evidence below of of it not connecting still

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port numbers are just conventions (or 'standards') used for particular protocols. You can certainly use different port numbers for your services.

If you have a **web server running on 8080** that is expecting HTTPS connections, you would need to:

- Select "Custom TCP" and port 8080 in the **Security Group**, then add the appropriate IP address range (such as `0.0.0.0/0` for the whole Internet, or perhaps just your specific IP address) -- you can ignore the 'protocol' field since is simply listing the 'standard' uses for each port number
- Point your web browser to port **8080**, such as:

```
https://ec2-54-91-36-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
```

Comment: ive added evidence in an update of me trying that (i did try that before)  is there perhaps some way to view the logs of my ec2 container to see whats happening? im a bit lost.